# Single Port Block RAM in verilog - spartan 6

Tags: verilog

I am trying to access a single port Block RAM. The below code is to fetch the instruction pointed by the program counter PC. I am able to infer a Single port block RAM until i use the 'execute" state in my code to write data into the RAM from register 'a'. But, when i add execute state as shown in the code, i am inferring a dual port RAM.

Also, the last line of the code 'data_out=mem[pc]' must be added to infer a RAM else i am not getting it.

Can somebody please explain why is it happening and how to avoid this? Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

```
module RAM_param(clk,data_out);
parameter n = 12;
parameter w = 16;

input clk;
reg read_write;


output reg [w-1:0] data_out;



parameter [1:0]
pc_val = 2'b00,
ifetch = 2'b01,
decode = 2'b10,
execute=2'b11;

reg [15:0]a;
reg [15:0]b;
reg [11:0] pc=12'd0;
reg [11:0] sp;
reg [11:0] addr;
reg [15:0] ir;
reg [15:0] mem [4095:0];
reg c,z,IEN;
reg [1:0]next_state=2'b00;
reg wen;




always@ (posedge clk)
begin

case(next_state)

pc_val:
        begin
                pc=pc+1;
                next_state<= ifetch;
        end

ifetch:     
        begin

            ir=mem[pc];

            next_state<=decode;
        end   

decode: 
        begin
            addr=ir[11:0];
            if(ir[15:12]==4'b0000)//LDA
                a=mem[addr];

            else if(ir[15:12]==4'b0001)//LDB
                b=mem[addr];

            else if (ir[15:12]==4'b0010)//STA
            begin
                wen=1;
                next_state<=execute;
            end 
        end

execute: begin
            if(wen==1)
            mem[addr]=a;
           end


endcase
data_out=mem[pc];
end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading 'data_out' from the ram on every clock cycle, and in the same cycle, depending on the next_state variable, trying to write to the ram.

You can't read and write the ram in the same cycle if you want it to be single port. So you'll either have to use a dual port ram, or put the 'data_out' mem read into a different state where you are not also writing to the ram.